# Display radio and div elements in vertical way

Tags: css

There's this structure of `radio` choices inside of a `form`.

```
<div id="hier_all">
    <h2 id="tit_hierarq" class="hierarq visible">Choose</h2>
    <h3 id="tit_hierarq_help" class="hierarq visible">one of the options</h3>
    <form id="form_hierarq" class="hierarq visible">

        <input id="hierarq0" class="hierarq visible" type="radio" name="radioButHierarq" value="0">
        <div id="hierarq0" class="hierarq visible">option 0</div>

        <input id="hierarq1" class="hierarq visible" type="radio" name="radioButHierarq" value="1">
        <div id="hierarq1" class="hierarq visible">option 1</div>
```

Right now, the sixteen choices there are to be shown (only two in the example) are displayed one next to another in a horizontal way.

I'd like to have the `radio` input as well as the accompanying `div` to be placed side by side. The next ones should appear right below, and so on, in a vertical way.

For `.hierarq`, tried to use `display: run-in`, but the elements are placed horizontally.
With `display: list-item`, items are placed vertically, but although `javascript` adds `hidden` to the `class` of each element in `form` (and removes `visible`), the `radio` choices and their `div` remain visible after an option is chosen.
If `display: block`, I get the same problem as with `display: list-item`.

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like [**this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/Xk3AB/1/)

if yes, instead of div you can use span. So that It will wrap next to radio option.

**html**

```
<p>
    <input id="hierarq0" class="hierarq visible" type="radio" name="radioButHierarq" value="0">
<span id="hierarq0" class="hierarq visible">option 0</span>

</p>
<p>
    <input id="hierarq1" class="hierarq visible" type="radio" name="radioButHierarq" value="1">
<span id="hierarq1" class="hierarq visible">option 1</span>

</p>
```

Comment: It's like that in the example.  I haven't used the '<p>' because didn't want to change `javascript` code where the form elements are built.  But, if there's no better option, I'll insert the '<p>'.  In the example, what does `<span>` do differently?

Comment: as I mentioned earlier, if you use span, the texts (option 0, option 1, etc..) will wrap next to radio button.

Comment: if you don't want to use any p tags and all, please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/tSG6R/1/